# WP Images not aligning as expected

Tags: css, wordpress, themes

Here's what's up. I've got a post that has images, and I'm trying to get them to wrap into the paragraph text, but it's not behaving the way I expect. Any insight? Probably a simple fix that I'm just missing.

Relevant styles

```
img.alignright { float: right; margin: 0 0 1em 1em; }
img.alignleft { float: left; margin: 0 1em 1em 0; }
img.aligncenter { display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; }
.alignright, .alignleft { display:inline;}
.alignright { float: right; }
.alignleft { float: left; }
.aligncenter { display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; }
.wp-caption {font-size:10px; max-width:100%;}
```

Page in question: http://dev.traction.media/mmsheeks/alice/i-spy/

Any pointers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

styles.css:91

```
.main p {
  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.3em;
  /* float: left; */
  margin: 1em auto;
}
```

Comment: As expected, simple stupid solution that I was just missing. Thanks!